# Код ревью тестового проекта Android Dev

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, mvp, rxandroid

Я начинающий Android разработчик и пытаюсь устроиться на работу. На одном из собеседованиях мне дали тестовое задание:

Требуется разработать клиент, отображающий погоду на неделю для указанного списка городов. Список городов предзадан в приложении, но также должна быть возможность дополнить его. 
Города доступны по горизонтальному скроллу (аналогично стандартным приложениям)
В качестве источника данных требуется использоватopenweathermap.org/api.
Особое внимание уделить архитектуре и разделению ответственностей.

Приложение было написано и добавлено в гитхаб
https://github.com/DMilyutin/Test-Weather

Использовал архитектуру MVP, Retrofit2, RxAndroid, Dagger2
В качестве БД используется Realm.

Необходима оценка опытных специалистов моего творения с указанием что и где не так сделано.
Заранее большое спасибо!!
P.S. Я самоучка, все что выхватил из интернета, применил.

Comment: Может и найдутся желающие, но данная площадка не предназначена для: фриланса, код-ревью (без проблемных участков, выложенных в топике), рекламных акций, продажи слонов и глотания шпаг

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Открыв view сразу увидел, что у вас перезентер создается в активити, поэтому поворот он не переживает, dependency rule нарушен, дальше не смотрел) Если не используете мокси, то хотя бы инжектите презентеры даггером в активити

Comment: @Valgaal Спасибо большое за уделенное время! В обязательном порядке посмотрю мокси.